# STI children don't show in active_admin's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic, single-table-inheritance

I have a Product model, set up with 4 children using STI.

My active_admin form looks like this:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :type, collection: Product.select_options
        f.input :title
        etc.
    end
    f.buttons
end
```

Relevant code from parent model:

```
  def self.select_options
    descendants.map{ |c| c.to_s }.sort
  end
```

Initializer:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  %w[product ring necklace bracelet earring].each do |c|
    require_dependency File.join("app","models","#{c}.rb")
  end
end
```

It all works fine and when I'm in the console I can do Product.select_options and it prints them out.

Why won't active_admin pick them up?  It simply gives me a blank drop down with a tick inside it.

Thanks

Comment: did you try :

`f.input :type, as: :select,  collection: Product.select_options`

Comment: I guess I hadn't as it now works.  Thanks very much.  If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You missed as: :select

Replace

```
f.input :type, collection: Product.select_options
```

With

```
f.input :type, as: :select, collection: Product.select_options
```